# Do I need to use git to track both database files and migrate scripts?

Tags: flask, flask-migrate

I am learning Flask by reading [Miguel Grinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database)'s awesome tutorial. In that chapter, he talked to use Flask-Migrate extension to cope with database schema changes. He has said the migration scripts need to be added to version control system, but how about the database file itself? Should it be added to `.gitignore` file or not? Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Personally I would keep backing up the db separated from git. There are a lot of arguments before and against it, and I would recommend looking up some literature not specifically connected to flask, such as [this one](https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you don't want to store the database in version control. If you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy as suggested by Miguel then there are ways to ensure that the database is created if it does not exist. However the data obviously would not be persisted.

So if you decide that you do not want to store the database file in git then use it is recommended to add it to the `.gitignore` file to ensure that it is not accidentally added to version control.

An example of why you wouldn't want to do this would be if you had a website running with lots of users. The users have entered and saved their data into your database through your flask application. Generally for production applications the database is hosted as a separate running application so therefore would not even be stored along with your code. The reason it is when developing flask applications this way is that it is very easy to use the builtin Python SQLLite. It doesn't require any additional programs to be running or configuration and makes development easier. By using something SQL Alchemy you can change SQL databases to, for example, postgresql in production or whatever suits you best. Flask-Migrate (created by Miguel) is an excellent library for database migrations as part of Flask.